# How do I remove the default blue box around footnotes on iOS Safari?

Tags: css

I have the following HTML:

```
<ol>
<li id="fn1"><p>Blah, blah, blah<a href="#fnref1" class="footnote-back">↩</a></p></li>
<li id="fn2"><p>Another footnote<a href="#fnref2" class="footnote-back">↩</a></p></li>
</ol>
```

On Chrome and Safari on the desktop this renders like this:

[image]

But on mobile Safari on my iPad and iPhone it renders like this:

[image]

I can't figure out how to remove the blue boxes around the cartoonish curly arrows. I just want them to be a plain curly arrow like they are on the desktop.

Does anyone know how to style these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default iOS renders some Unicode characters as emojis. This can be prevented by using `&#x`-starting HTML entities with `FE0E` (text) variant ([see list](ftp://unicode.org/Public/8.0.0/ucd/StandardizedVariants.html)). In this case, it's `&#x21A9;&#xFE0E;`

```html
<ol>
<li id="fn1"><p>Blah, blah, blah<a href="#fnref1" class="footnote-back">&#x21A9;&#xFE0E;</a></p></li>
<li id="fn2"><p>Another footnote<a href="#fnref2" class="footnote-back">&#x21A9;&#xFE0E;</a></p></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: I can't control the character that's inserted (output from Pandoc) but if I replace it with JQuery: `$('.footnote-back').html('&#x21A9;');` it doesn't seem to change anything...

Comment: @GarryPettet Oh, right. To force text variant, it must be `&#x21A9;&#xFE0E;`. Corrected my answer

Comment: Thank you so much. Works perfectly!